# Download a file when user session expired and then logged on

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my application if user session expires, user is logged out. But in one case it causes a problem – user clicks on a button to dowload a file POST method from url /Reports/Download, his session expired so he is redirecting to login form under address: `http://localhost/Authentication/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fReports%2fDownload` - as you can see here at the end of url is ReturnUrl, so after logged on user is redirecting to /Reports/Download what causes error because this method allows only POST not GET.
I could change this method on GET but then user can't log on because each time when user clicks log in button he downloads a file.
What should I do?

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Download", "Reports", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="DateFrom" />
    <input type="text" name="DateTo" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class ReportsController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Download(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "report.xls"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        //myMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream); <-- here save file content

        Response.End();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you are trying to solve session expiration issue while user is still downloading file. Use sliding session expiration technique.

Comment: But this file is really small. Simply user is sometimes on a page and tries to download file when few seconds ago his session expired.

Comment: Checkout this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939911/httppost-to-returnurl-after-redirect)